# How to fix 'my dropdown' with three levels

Tags: html, css, stylus

I am trying to make a drop-down with three levels. But when I hover the first level, the second one appears a little over the first level and on the left side. I want to have the second level in the middle of the first level. And I don't know how can I have a third level in the right side of the second level.

```css
.middle,
.bottom {
  background-color: #1565c0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li:after,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li:after {
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width 0.5s ease, background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li:hover:after,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: #003c8f;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu>li,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu>li {
  width: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  text-align: -moz-center;
  z-index: 1;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu>li:hover,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu>li:hover {
  cursor: hand;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu>li:hover>ul.second-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu>li:hover>ul.second-level-menu {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu a,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu a {
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu {
  display: none;
  background-color: #1565c0;
  z-index: 1;
  emphasized text border-top: 5px solid #f00;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu li ul.third-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu li ul.third-level-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">

  <div class="middle">

    <ul class="top-level-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#!">Acerca</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia" target="_blank">Historia</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ route('missionvision') }}">Misión y Visión</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Organigrama</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#!">Carreras</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Enfermería</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Informática</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gastronomía</a>
            <li>
              <li><a href="#">Contabilidad</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Admisión</a>
          <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">New York</a>
              <ul class="third-level-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">Calendario</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Here a little picture of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code below - I have added many small changes.

Some notes to remember:

1). An absolute element (almost always) should have a parent which is "relative". Your child "ul" containers were set to absolute, but the parent "li" elements were not set to "position: relative", hence the "ul"-s could not be positioned properly.

2). In order to position your 2nd level to center I gave it a width: 70%, 10% from left and right, 5% padding for left and right.

```css
.middle,
.bottom {
  background-color: #1565c0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li:after,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li:after {
  height: 3px;
  width: 0px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: transparent;
  transition: width 0.5s ease, background-color 0.5s ease;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li:hover:after,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background: #003c8f;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu>li,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu>li {
  width: 23%;
  padding: 10px 1%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  text-align: -webkit-center;
  text-align: -moz-center;
  position: relative;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu>li:hover,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu>li:hover {
  cursor: hand;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu a,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu a {
  font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu {
  display: none;
  background-color: #1565c0;
  border-top: 5px solid #f00;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu>li:hover>ul.second-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu>li:hover>ul.second-level-menu {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 10px 5%;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 2;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu li,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu li{
  position: relative;
}


.middle ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu li ul.third-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu li ul.third-level-menu {
  display: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.middle ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu li:hover > ul.third-level-menu,
.bottom ul.top-level-menu li ul.second-level-menu li:hover > ul.third-level-menu {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 95%;
  background: red;
  text-align: left;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation">

  <div class="middle">

    <ul class="top-level-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#!">Acerca</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia" target="_blank">Historia</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ route('missionvision') }}">Misión y Visión</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Organigrama</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#!">Carreras</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Enfermería</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Informática</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Gastronomía</a>
            <li>
              <li><a href="#">Contabilidad</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#!">Admisión</a>
          <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
            <li>
              <a href="#">New York</a>
              <ul class="third-level-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#!">Calendario</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: Man thank you so much, works perfectly. I'm was trying to solved this issue all day. Really really thanks